# Estimating result count of a query

Tags: sql, sql-server, statistics, estimation

I'd like to estimate the count of results of a query which is a JOIN between 5-10 tables containing large amount of data (~500 milion rows each table).

Such query takes for eg. 20-30 minutes to execute in the environment in which I was testing.

I want to get an estimate within 5 seconds. What are the ways to get this in MSSQL?

I'm thinking to take a sample out of each table and run the query against the sample but not sure if this will return a fair estimate.

Comment: How about analyzing estimated query plan?

Comment: If you have a way to collect your data in similar size groups (like by date, one per group month), you could extrapolate from that, maybe using a view. I don't think you have a way to get an estimate of such amount of data in 5 seconds.

Comment: If I can assume based on the amount of data in the tables that most of the records are static, but the data is growing. If you can figure out a way to distinguish "old" data vs "new" data (for instance using record creation date, rowversion, etc). Then you can build a process which would pre-calculate "old" data record count periodically (weekly or nightly) and you would calculate "new" record count on a smaller set of data (you would need proper indexes) on the fly and add them up. Then it might work in 5 sec.

Comment: @JamesZ estimated query plan doesn't work with parameterized queries.